# Format and Validate CSS with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's there a jquery plugin to validate CSS ?

I mean, i yould like to let the user enter is own CSS in a textbox and validate if is a valid CSS with jquery ?

example :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NationalRegular';
    src: url('http://localced.com/national-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('National'), local('NationalRegular'), url('http://localced.com/national-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://localced.com/national-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://localced.com/national-regular-webfont.svg#webfontHGfqMJAZ') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
***notgoodCSS***:this is not good;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the W3C validator on your own server.

Execute the commandline and return the result to jquery (through an Ajax call).

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Jquery, but do you know about the W3C [CSS Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)? You can enter a url to a css file and it will validate it as valid or invalid and tell you how to correct it.