# How to validate css when we add css in textarea value?

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I've write css in textarea but need to validate that css which I'm writing it's properties and value is correct or not ?

I've to develop a feature like real time css change along with validating that css For instance if I write .abc { text : text; } then this text is not a valid property nor valid css so I have to show notification/error in textarea itself like : **This text is not a valid css**

**Html Code** :

```
<textarea id="txtCSS" name="txtCSS" rows="14" cols="50">
    .FC{color:blue; margin: 40px; padding: 50px;}
    .cf{color:blue; margin: 40px; padding: 50px; }
</textarea>
<label class="FC">Some Text</label>
<div class="cf">test Text</div>
```

**JavaScript Code :**

```
function render(value) {
        let previewStyle = document.getElementById('previewStyle');
        if (!previewStyle) {
            addStyle(value);
        } else {
            previewStyle.innerText = value;
        }
    }
    function addStyle(styles) {
        /* Create style document */
        const css = document.createElement('style');
        css.type = 'text/css';
        css.id = 'previewStyle';
        if (css.styleSheet) {
            css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
        } else {
            css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
        }
        /* Append style to the tag name */
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
    }
    const text = document.getElementById('txtCSS');
    text.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        const content = e.target.value;
        render(content);
    });
    render(text.value);
```

Referance Image :

[image]

Comment: Note: there's a difference between "syntax valid" css and css that's "valid".  eg add `body {display:none;}` to your textarea...  you might like to rethink your approach: add an iframe and change the css in that iframe so that it doesn't affect the page that you're using to input the values.

Comment: Previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433902/format-and-validate-css-with-jquery) (though in 2010, so may be a newer solution) - quick google and most suggestions are, like that answer, to use an existing validator, either online or download.

Comment: @freedomn-m  is this will be used in my existing project as I've to develop a feature like real time css change along with validating that css 

For instance if I write .abc { text : text; } then this text is not a valid property nor valid css so I have to show notification/error in textarea itself like : This text is not a valid css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format and Validate CSS with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433902/format-and-validate-css-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below It should work

```js
   const validatorURL = 'https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator' +
  '?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&profile=css3&output=json';
fetch(validatorURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(results => console.log(results))
```

Comment: Yes this is working for me 

For Refernce : https://jsfiddle.net/Kaushal_Joshi/gfu8aL9j/17/